# Flutter GetX forms validation

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, flutter-getx, flutter-form-builder

I am looking for an example of how to handle forms and validation in best practice with GetX?
Is there any good example of that or can someone show me an example of how we best can do this?

Comment: you can see getx extension for vs code. It has some snippets for getx, also getx forms. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=get-snippets.get-snippets

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could use GetX's observables to dynamically update form fields & submit button.

I make no claim that this is a best practice.  I'm sure there's better ways of accomplishing the same.  But it's fun to play around with how GetX can be used to perform validation.

## Form + Obx

Two widgets of interest that rebuild based on Observable value changes:

1. TextFormField

   - InputDecoration's `errorText` changes & will rebuild this widget
   - `onChanged: fx.usernameChanged` doesn't cause rebuilds. This calls a function in the controller `usernameChanged(String val)` when form field input changes.
   - It just updates the `username` observable with a new value.
   - Could be written as:
   - `onChanged: (val) => fx.username.value = val`
2. ElevatedButton (a "Submit" button)

   - `onPressed` function can change between `null` and a function
   - `null` disables the button (only way to do so in Flutter)
   - a function here will enable the button

```
class FormObxPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormObxPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FormX fx = Get.put(FormX()); // controller

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Form Validation'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Obx(
                    () {
                  print('rebuild TextFormField ${fx.errorText.value}');
                  return TextFormField(
                      onChanged: fx.usernameChanged, // controller func
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Username',
                          errorText: fx.errorText.value // obs
                      )
                  );
                },
              ),
              Obx(
                    () => ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: fx.submitFunc.value, // obs
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## GetX Controller

Explanation / breakdown below

```
class FormX extends GetxController {
  RxString username = RxString('');
  RxnString errorText = RxnString(null);
  Rxn<Function()> submitFunc = Rxn<Function()>(null);

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    debounce<String>(username, validations, time: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  void validations(String val) async {
    errorText.value = null; // reset validation errors to nothing
    submitFunc.value = null; // disable submit while validating
    if (val.isNotEmpty) {
      if (lengthOK(val) && await available(val)) {
        print('All validations passed, enable submit btn...');
        submitFunc.value = submitFunction();
        errorText.value = null;
      }
    }
  }

  bool lengthOK(String val, {int minLen = 5}) {
    if (val.length < minLen) {
      errorText.value = 'min. 5 chars';
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> available(String val) async {
    print('Query availability of: $val');
    await Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 1),
            () => print('Available query returned')
    );

    if (val == "Sylvester") {
      errorText.value = 'Name Taken';
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  void usernameChanged(String val) {
    username.value = val;
  }

  Future<bool> Function() submitFunction() {
    return () async {
      print('Make database call to create ${username.value} account');
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('User account created'));
      return true;
    };
  }
}
```

#### Observables

Starting with the three observables...

```
  RxString username = RxString('');
  RxnString errorText = RxnString(null);
  Rxn<Function()> submitFunc = Rxn<Function()>(null);
```

`username` will hold whatever was last input into the TextFormField.

`errorText` is instantiated with `null` initial value so the username field is not "invalid" to begin with. If *not* null (even empty string), TextFormField will be rendered red to signify invalid input.  When a non-valid input is in the field, we'll show an error message. (`min. 5 chars` in example:)

[image: username too short]

`submitFunc` is an observable for holding a submit button function or `null`, since functions in Dart are actually objects, this is fine.  The `null` value initial assignment will disable the button.

#### onInit

The `debounce` worker calls the `validations` function 500ms after changes to the `username` observable end.

`validations` will receive `username.value` as its argument.

[More on workers](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#workers).

#### Validations

Inside `validations` function we put any types of validation we want to run: minimum length, bad characters, name already taken, names we personally dislike due to childhood bullies, etc.

For added realism, the `available()` function is `async`.  Commonly this would query a database to check username availability so in this example, there's a fake 1 second delay before returning this validation check.

`submitFunction()` returns a function which will replace the null value in `submitFunc` observable when we're satisfied the form has valid inputs and we allow the user to proceed.

A little more realistic, we'd prob. expect some return value from the submit button function, so we could have the button function return a future bool:

```
  Future<bool> Function() submitFunction() {
    return () async {
      print('Make database call to create ${username.value} account');
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('User account created'));
      return true;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 22):

GetX is not the solution for everything but it has some few utility methods which can help you achieve what you want. For example you can use a `validator` along with `SnackBar` for final check. Here is a code snippet that might help you understand the basics.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: emailController,
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  validator: (value) {
    if (!GetUtils.isEmail(value))
      return "Email is not valid";
    else
      return null;
  },               
),
```

`GetUtils` has few handy methods for quick validations and you will have to explore each method to see if it fits your need.

Comment: Awesome comment, using GetUtils and autovalidatemode make this simpler!!